# Visual Studio won't build .dll anymore, only .dll.recipe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

I'm trying to make a mod for a game in C++. I'm following a tutorial for the SDK to make a simple example mod. I setup all the preferences and was able to successfully compile and use a DLL.
As an experiment, I tried to make functions accessable via __declspec, but then realized that an external program won't have access to the game's memory, so I abandoned this idea.

Today I wanted to continue with my mod and deleted those __declspec declarations again. But now, if I try to compile my mod it will only compile a dll.recipe file. I even deleted the output folder to make sure it's rebuilding everything, but it still won't give me a DLL file.

I didn't change anything in the preferences or project settings since I first started the tutorial.

I'm lost. What went wrong and what do I need to change to make it build a DLL file again?

Comment: I believe if you don't export any symbols using `__declspec(dllexport)`  you don't get a dll unless you have a .def file.

Comment: Do a Rebuild on the DLL project and copy/paste the contents of the Output Window into the question.

Comment: As stated in my post, I'm making a mod for a game using a SDK. The include files would have the needed __declspec(dllexport). And as stated, it used to work just a few days ago. But by making my own __declspec function I must have messed something up that I can't figure out.

Comment: sometimes deleting the .vs folder of your solution can help. exit visual studio first.

Answer (score 9):

It turned out there were 2 release folders in the project directory: One was projectName\x64\release and the other was projectName\projectName\x64\release.

The former contains the .dll file and the latter contains the .dll.recipe file.
So it was always there, I was just searching in the wrong folder.

Comment: To clarify if you have the solution and project to not use the same directory, the builds in the project directory will contain recipe files. The solution's root has its own builds directory containing the .lib files for all c++ library projects in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the Output File path given in your project property page, there will be your .dll generated; regardless of .dll.recipe